How do I move my HTML border forward of my animated image?
Currently, I have a border surrounding the HTML of my website, so that it surrounds all content on every page. However, on my home page I have an image that slides in when the page loads and currently it slides over the border, and I would really like it to slide underneath the border instead. I've been searching through W3 schools for awhile but couldn't come up with a solution. How can this be accomplished?
html {
    background-color: black;
    border-style: inset;
    border-color: antiquewhite;
    border-width: 5px;
}

Here is my HTML code, and here is my image code as it is now:
.authorimage {
    width: 33%;
    padding: 2rem;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-name: slidein;
}

And here is the animation code, just for reference:
@keyframes slidein {
    from {
      transform: translateX(-45rem);
    }
    to {
      transform: translateX(0);
    }
}

Thanks in advance for the insight.
I tried Z-index but that resulted in the HTML's border vanishing behind all the content of the page. I also tried using pseudo-elements and pseudo-classes but the results were much the same.

As the border is just for visual effect you could put it on an after pseudo element.

Use clip-path:


* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  --border-width: 20px;
  border: solid var(--border-width) red;
  /* min-height: 100dvh; */
}

body{
  clip-path: polygon(
    var(--border-width) var(--border-width),
    calc(100% - var(--border-width)) var(--border-width),
    calc(100% - var(--border-width)) calc(100% - var(--border-width)),
    var(--border-width) calc(100% - var(--border-width))
  );
  margin: calc(-1 * var(--border-width));
  padding: var(--border-width);
}
img {
  animation:slidein 1s infinite;
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

@keyframes slidein {
  from {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}
<img src="https://picsum.photos/666/160" alt="">



